# how to change the color of md-input-container placeholder when focus?

Tags: css, angular, input, placeholder

I'm using angular 4 and I have an md-input-container that has a placeholder. when I type something in the input, the placeholder is shown as a label. how can I change the color of the placeholder in this situation?

```
 <md-input-container class="mb-1 data_font">
   <input mdInput placeholder="Full name">
 </md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usally working with `mat-form-field` as a wrapper for the `input` field.

```
<mat-form-field class="mb-1 data_font">
  <input mdInput placeholder="Full name">
</mat-form-field>
```

Now you can add the following code to your CSS:

```
.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  color: red;
}
```

Keep in mind, if you want to change your color palette in general you should consider using a theme: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Comment: but it's not working in angular 4! what if I have an md-input-container?

Comment: @fariba.j mhm, I can't find the angular 4 material docs. can you create a plunkr - then I will edit the code. Or basically just debug the label and look for the `focus` class added on the container. maybe it's